# SwiftUI Image with high height layout

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, size, resizable

I'm trying to get a basic thing, but I can't make it work!

I would like to have a VStack that contains a text an image and a second text.
Everything should be visible on the screen. So the Image should resize (crop top and bottom) to give spaces for the two texts... but not.

Without `.scaledToFill()` it's working well, but the image is stretched

The problem (I think) is because the image has a high height!

(I tried with GeometryReader, fixedSize, layoutPriority, but nothing that I tried works)

The image is from Wikipedia: [Image link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Isabella_of_France_by_Froissart.png/1024px-Isabella_of_France_by_Froissart.png)

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text("Text 1")

            Image("image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()

            Text("Text 2")
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[Simulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svWvm.jpg)

What is needed:
[Image of what is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGPfs.jpg)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a way

```
Color.clear
    .background(Image("image")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill())
    .clipped()
```

Embedding the image as background of a clear `Color`, the image is limited to the parent size!

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHtd9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
struct TestView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 8) { // You can alternatively increase the spacing and remove the padding for the image
        Text("Text 1")

        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .padding()

        Text("Text 2")
    }.background(Color.blue)
     .padding() // Note padding here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, with this image, The Text 1 and Text 2 are quite outside of safe area in iphone 13, and not present in iphone 8 device :/ 
https://imgur.com/a/iAjgkyb

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text("Text 1")

            Image("image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()

            Text("Text 2")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

You could also use the maxHeight frame parameter to frame the view if you know how big you'd want it to be. You can also do this on the image itself.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text("Text 1")

            Image("image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()

            Text("Text 2")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .frame(maxHeight: 500) //500 can be any value of your choice
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But, for the first code example, it's not working (either iphone 13 and ipone 8) https://imgur.com/a/7YAt8dk
And For the fixed height, I want to avoid that because of all screen height are differents

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for a way to consider `Safe Area`. because at the second image all contents respect to safe area while the first image don't. However the code seems to do so by default unless we indicate to ignore safe area by using `.ignoresSafeArea()`. Look at the view where you called `TextView`, You might use `ZStack` with a blue background that affects its children.

If not you should used `scaledToFit` instead of `scaledToFill` because as I see both images, the second one is cropped.

Comment: You mean embeding the VStack inside an ZStack?
If yes, it's not working :/

Comment: I didn't mean that! I meant you may have used .ignoresSafeArea() in your code based on the first picture. @Arnaud514

Comment: No, TestView is the only View displayed! Imagine it like ContentView.
TestView is the only thing called in the @main body inside WindowGroup.
No .ignoresSafeArea() anywhere!

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind is that you should use scaledToFit instead of scaledToFill. So I added it to the answer. @Arnaud514

Comment: ScaledToFit is working for the height, but the width is not at the max possible screen width, so it's not the behavior that I want! 

I manage to fix the problem by embedding the image in a Color view
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743896/17951086

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [AsyncImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage) with placeholder to load the image

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text("Text 1")            
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Isabella_of_France_by_Froissart.png/1024px-Isabella_of_France_by_Froissart.png")){ image in
                image.resizable()
            }placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            
            Text("Text 2")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks but I want to avoid fixing size with .frame() to be able to enjoy the full view in different screen sizes (just the image should be resized in height)